# Autohotkey use CapsLock key as modifier key

Tags: windows, autohotkey

How might I use the CapsLock key as a modifier type key in autohotkey?

For example currently I am currently doing the following:

```
t=0
CapsLock::t:=!t
#If t 
  y::6
  u::7
```

Ideally I would like to just be able to hold down the CapsLock key to trigger the keys.

Basically is there a similar way of writing the above code except for the following?

```
CapsLock & y::6
```

Comment: I think this questions should be in stackoverflow.com

Comment: @crazypotato Nope, they are fine here.

Comment: Why you cant use CapsLock & y ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If hold down CAPS LOCK

```
u::
if (GetKeyState("CapsLock")=1){
    u::6
}
else
{
    send u
}
```

IF TOOGLE CAPS LOCK

```
u::
if (GetKeyState("CapsLock","t")=1){
    u::6
}
else
{
    send u
}
```

[Get current keyboard layout](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/43043-get-current-keyboard-layout/)

**Update:**

```
#If GetKeyState("CapsLock")=1
  y::6
  u::7
```

Comment: I would like to not have to write out the else statement because it is quiet repetitive and not clean

Comment: I had to change it to `#If GetKeyState("CapsLock", "P") = 1` to work.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a much simpler solution:

```
#SingleInstance, Force

SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff

;CapsLock & S to open Slack
CapsLock & s::
    Run, Slack.exe
    Return
```

*Note: this will disable the CapsLock key's default behavior*