# Use ScrollLock key as a modifier with AutoHotkey

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

**How to use the <kbd>ScrollLock</kbd> key as a modifier with AutoHotkey?** Example:

<kbd>ScrollLock</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> : Launch software1.exe

<kbd>ScrollLock</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> : Launch software2.exe

<kbd>ScrollLock</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> : Launch software3.exe

etc.

I've already looked at [this topic](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/51959-using-capslock-as-another-modifier-key/) and [Autohotkey use CapsLock key as modifier key](https://superuser.com/questions/799557/autohotkey-use-capslock-key-as-modifier-key) but it seems specific to <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
ScrollLock & F1:: Run notepad
ScrollLock & F2:: Run wordpad
ScrollLock & F3:: Run iexplore.exe
```

If you don't want ScrollLock to be turned on and off every time you use it in a hotkey definition, then you have two options:

The simplest way is to [force the key to stay](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetNumScrollCapsLockState.htm) off permanently by adding

```
SetScrollLockState, AlwaysOff
```

in the [auto-execute section](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto) (top of the script).

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force

SetScrollLockState, AlwaysOff

ScrollLock & F1:: Run notepad
ScrollLock & F2:: Run wordpad
ScrollLock & F3:: Run iexplore.exe
```

or you [check its state](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm#ex1) every time you use it in a hotkey definition and restore this state after releasing it:

```
ScrollLock & F1::
    Run notepad
    If GetKeyState("ScrollLock","T")
        SetScrollLockState, On
    else
        SetScrollLockState, Off
return
```

Comment: The same applies if you want to use  **Capslock** or  **NumLock** as a modifier with AutoHotkey.